# How should I access my hdfs file system from my desktop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I want to run jar file of a map reduce job. My input and output files are in hdfs. My WordCountJob.jar file is in Desktop.

Input file (inside hdfs) : `/rucha/input/sample.txt`
Output file(inside hdfs) : `/rucha/output/result`

`hadoop jar WordCountJob.jar /usr/local/hadoop/input /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/output/result`

So what would be the command for running this jar file which takes input from hdfs and stores result in hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the command as below:
hadoop jar local path for the jar/WordCountJob.jar fully qualified classname /rucha/input/sample.txt /rucha/output/result

Classname you can find in the main program.